# Like newspaper and television, how internet can become a massive tool of information manipulation and control over the people?

Tags: reference-request, critical-theory, philosophy-of-technology, social-critique

As per the trend we see, any type of system in this world, ultimately gets corrupted. Leading to a final particular state, where power remains on top and rest on the bottom. No matter it's  religious system, money system, government system, religious system, media ( news paper, television ), or any system that can be thought of.

A very common pattern in the origin of all these systems, is that they start from being virtuous. They help people a lot, they are like a life savior. Then gradually, people become used to it. They are blindly followed. The people controlling the system get powerful and powerful. The whistle blowers get weaker and weaker, and most of them are eliminated. The people are offered addiction, so that number of followers can be maintained and controlled. Everything is engulfed by the system.

So, with this pattern in mind, is it the case, internet too, that today not only seems to be very virtuous, has also entered in every smallest activity of our lives ( unlike tv and newspaper, that still were limited to bedroom and morning time ), would become one of the biggest tool to control the people. And this time, there is not going to be any escape.

- what philosophers have said that the internet has or had a positive potential, but has or is becoming something which is negatively affecting us?

Comment: obviously the opportunity for surveillance, advertising, etc. (?) is absolutely huge. one would hope it has a +ve side tho

Comment: why is this question opinion based? i don't think anyone understands the rules of the site tbh

Comment: Robert Epstein in Aeon magazine: The new Mind Control https://aeon.co/essays/how-the-internet-flips-elections-and-alters-our-thoughts

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.uky.edu/~drlane/capstone/mass/determinism.htm) looks like a pretty, if old, page from the University of Kentucky

> Technological Determinism [in media studies] state [sic] that media technology shapes how we as
>   individuals in a society think, feel, act, and how are society
>   operates as we move from one technological age to another (Tribal-
>   Literate- Print- Electronic).

Seems like a given, to an extent.

One question would be whether the internet is a neutral technology.

[image]

A page from this book, 2013, neatly says that few philosophers believe technologies are neutral:

- New Directions in the Philosophy of Technology edited by Joseph C.
  Pitt

As such, we could ask if the internet is the sort of technology which is more likely to shape our life in a positive way?

There will be academic research into this, which I don't feel confident in quoting from. But, given that:

1. The internet intimately shapes our life
2. The value of the internet, even if not fixed, is not neutral

It seems fair to suggest that the internet may negatively affect our thinking etc., independent of how we use it.

---

Notwithstanding, of course, how it ***can*** be used to sell us a false narrative, etc..